# OSPF/BGP/Route-Map issue

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, ospf

hello to all my friends...
i configured this scenario **but** R1 only traces until 10.10.13.3 (R3) !
plz help me...

- All routers have a loopback `0` interface `X.X.X.X/32` where `X` is the number of the router.
- Configure OSPF on R1, R2, R3 and advertise `10.10.12.0/24, 10.10.13.0/24` and loopback `0` subnets
- Configure OSPF on R4, R5 and advertise `150.45.45.0/26` and loopback 0 subnets
- Configure full iBGP mesh in AS 123, use loopback 0 interface for peering
- Configure iBGP in AS 45, use loopback 0 interface for peering
- Configure eBGP between AS 123 and AS 45
- Advertise R1 loopback 0 and `150.45.45.0/26` in BGP
- Ensure AS 123 will use the link between R3-R5 towards network `150.45.45.0/26`. Use MED attribute only.
- Ensure AS 45 will use the link between R3-R5 towards network 1.1.1.1/32. Use MED attribute only.

[image]

#### all configs

```
R6
    router ospf 10
     log-adjacency-changes
     network 1.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 area 0
     network 10.10.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
     network 10.10.13.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
    !
    router bgp 123
     no synchronization
     bgp log-neighbor-changes
     network 1.1.1.1 mask 255.255.255.255
     neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 123
     neighbor 2.2.2.2 update-source Loopback0
     neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 123
     neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
     no auto-summary
```

R2

```
router ospf 10
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 2.2.2.2 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.10.12.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
router bgp 123
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 123
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 remote-as 123
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 3.3.3.3 next-hop-self
 neighbor 24.0.0.2 remote-as 45
 neighbor 24.0.0.2 route-map RM-SET-MED out
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip prefix-list NET-1 seq 5 permit 1.1.1.1/32
!
!
!
route-map RM-SET-MED permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list NET-1
 set metric 20
```

R3

```
router ospf 10
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 3.3.3.3 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 10.10.13.0 0.0.0.255 area 0
!
router bgp 123
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 123
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 remote-as 123
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 2.2.2.2 next-hop-self
 neighbor 35.0.0.2 remote-as 45
 neighbor 35.0.0.2 route-map RM-SET-MED out
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip prefix-list NET-1 seq 5 permit 1.1.1.1/32
!
!
!
route-map RM-SET-MED permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list NET-1
 set metric 10
!
```

R4

```
router ospf 100
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 4.4.4.4 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 150.45.45.4 0.0.0.0 area 0
!
router bgp 45
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 150.45.45.0 mask 255.255.255.192
 neighbor 5.5.5.5 remote-as 45
 neighbor 5.5.5.5 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 5.5.5.5 next-hop-self
 neighbor 24.0.0.1 remote-as 123
 neighbor 24.0.0.1 route-map RM-SET-MED out
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip prefix-list NET-150 seq 5 permit 150.45.45.0/26
!
!
!
route-map RM-SET-MED permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list NET-150
 set metric 20
```

R5

```
router ospf 100
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 5.5.5.5 0.0.0.0 area 0
 network 150.45.45.5 0.0.0.0 area 0
!
router bgp 45
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 150.45.45.0 mask 255.255.255.192
 neighbor 4.4.4.4 remote-as 45
 neighbor 4.4.4.4 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 4.4.4.4 next-hop-self
 neighbor 35.0.0.1 remote-as 123
 neighbor 35.0.0.1 route-map RM-SET-MED out
 no auto-summary
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
!
ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
ip prefix-list NET-150 seq 5 permit 150.45.45.0/26
!
!
!
route-map RM-SET-MED permit 10
 match ip address prefix-list NET-150
 set metric 10
```

Comment: I hope to be a professional NTMAN guy :) 1+ because I like you..boooos

Comment: Can you clarify if R6 is actually R1 and source/destination of your trace?

Comment: I'm curious where this scenario came from.  A sample lab?  A real work problem?  A homework assignment?

Comment: R6 is R1.actualy hostname of R6, is R1.sorce is R6(R1) and destination is network of 150.45.45.0. this is a sample lab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you used command

```
traceroute 150.45.45.5
```

or

```
traceroute 150.45.45.5 source l0
```

?

Keep in mind that R4 and R5 have only route to 1.1.1.1/32 in AS 123 and that if you do traceroute 150.45.45.5 from R1, it will by default IP of outgoing interface as a source IP (in this case 10.10.13.1), to which R4 and R5 don't have a route.

Always consider not only if your side have a route to the destination but also if the remote side has a route back to you.

Comment: i used : 
traceroute 150.45.45.5 .
R5 traces only  35.0.0.1 .

Comment: that's the problem, if you use traceroute 150.45.45.5 then the source IP of the icmp probes will be 10.10.13.1, to which R5 doesn't have a route back. While using traceroute 150.45.45.5 source loopback0 will work. So there is no problem in the configuration. The problem is in your verification (traceroute).

Comment: `R1(R6)#traceroute 150.45.45.5 source lo 0        `            
and            
`R5#traceroute 1.1.1.1 source fastethernet 0/0       `          
when we write upper commands,our traceroute is successful.
because we advertise only loopback 0 of R1(R6) and fastethernet 0/0 of R5 (150.45.45.0/26) in BGP.